# convex_hull of a geometry

Tags: python, shapely

I need to get a convex_hull of a polygon. I'm using shapely. Nt sure how to apply convex_hull to get the result I need:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
p = Polygon(((0,0),(2,0),(2,2),(0,2),(1,1)))
```

The result I need. I don't know how to get the coordingates including repeating the first:

```
In[]: p.convex_hull   # How to get the resulted coordinates?
Out[]:
((0,0),(2,0),(2,2),(0,2),(0,0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
p = Polygon(((0,0),(2,0),(2,2),(0,2),(1,1)))
x = p.convex_hull
a, b = x.exterior.coords.xy
tuple(list(zip(a,b)))
```

Comment: Thanks, Using your idea I substituted your iteration with **tuple(list(zip(a,b))))**